# Creating Modular templates with template inheritance

Tags: python, html, django

I am new to Django and I am practicing template inheritance. I am currently having trouble inheriting templates on the 3rd level. The base level is a template that my whole site uses (ex: navbars). The second level is the content of my site. However this content is a bit lengthy so I took a portion(`contactform.html`) of it and created its own HTML file for that portion.

I am able to get my `home.html` into my `index.html` like so

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
  <link href="{% static "css/boothie.css" %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <script src="{% static "js/boothie.js" %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static "js/jquery.easing.1.3.js" %}"></script>

  <title>Boothie</title>
</head>
<body>
  {% block content %}{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

Within my `home.html` I want to include my `contactform.html`. This is what I have so far.

```
{% extends "index/index.html" %}

{% load staticfiles %}

{% block content %}


   ...
   ...
   ...stuff...

<!-- contact -->

{% block contactform %}{% endblock %}

{% endblock %}
```

My `contactform.html`:

```
{% extends "home/home.html" %}

{% load staticfiles %}

{% block contactform %}

<section id="contact">
   <!-- HTML! -->
</section>

{% endblock %}
```

This is what is currently in my home/views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views import generic


class HomeView(generic.TemplateView):
    template_name = "home/home.html"
```

my home/urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

from home.views import HomeView

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', HomeView.as_view(), name="home"),
)
```

TEMPLATE_DIRS:

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'home'),
)
```

here is a picture of my project structure:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need to `extend`, instead `include`

Example, keep the contents of the `contact_form.html` with just the required html content (without the extends, and the `block` tag, etc..), and then [`include` the html snippet](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#include). Now, django would do the magic for you - The included snippet would have all the context variables too.

```
{% extends ".." %}

{% load staticfiles %}

{% block content %}


   ...
   ...
   ...stuff...

   {% include /path/to/contactform.html %}

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: What would I have to do to make a functional form? Your help has enabled me to include the view into the page! Thanks! But I dont think I can submit the form and its contents into the DB yet.

Comment: Are you getting an error of some sort? Just examine the generated HTML - it should be a straightforward include. In other words, you would get _exactly_ as if you had the html snippet in place. Just make sure the context variables names are what the snippet expects..

Answer (score 3):

Instead of inheriting, just include the contactform template in the home template. In home/home.html put:

```
<section id="contact">
  {% include 'home/contactform.html' %}
</section>
```